# .htaccess is not working in my PHP MVC Framework

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am building my own PHP MVC framework from scratch on ubuntu. `.htaccess` file is not properly working in it. The folder structure and the `.htaccess` file content are as bellow.

### Folder Structure

```
/MyMVCProject
/controllers
     index.php
     help.php
/libs
/modles
/views
.htaccess
index.php
```

### `.htaccess` File content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I type `localh0st/MyMVCProject/help` it gives me the following error.

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /MyMVCProject/help was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localh0st Port 80

And I'm sure I have enabled mod_rewrite.

Comment: Might it be, that you made mistake here `localh0st` and actually you were trying to do `localhost`?

Comment: Hi Eugene I purposely did that when I posted the question on "stackoverflow".

Comment: Okey. Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: What URL is your application expecting? For instance, a request for `localh0st/MyMVCProject/help` would result in the request be routed to: `index.php?url=MyMVCProject/help` - is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it this way and from `$_REQUEST` array you can get url parameter and handle it in your index.php file.

Also for testing purpose add

```
echo <pre>;
print_r($_REQUEST);
echo </pre>;
```

at first lines of `index.php`

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following RewriteRule (Copied and bit modified from Zend framework)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Tried this. Same result :-(. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same thing, in my case the error was produced when I had a `help.php` file in the same directory. Don't know exactly why this happens...

Comment: This could happen if `MultiViews` is enabled, since this will cause `/help` to be internally rewritten to `/help.php` (if `help.php` exists as a physical file in that directory) before mod_rewrite gets to rewrite the request. In which case, you can disable `MultiViews` in per-directory .htaccess: `Options -MultiViews`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
RewriteBase /MyMVCProject
```

to your .htaccess file.